# what is the correct css selector in this code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

this is my current code:

```
import time
import threading
import pandas as pd
from math import nan
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'p.whitespace-nowrap',
        'game': 'a div:has(>a[title])',
        'score': 'a a[title]+div:has(+a[title])',
        'home_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)',
        'draw_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)+div:nth-last-of-type(3)',
        'away_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:nth-last-of-type(2)',
    }

    events, current_group = [], {}
    pgDate = pgSoup.select_one('h1.title[id="next-matches-h1"]')
    if pgDate: pgDate = pgDate.get_text().split(',', 1)[-1].strip()
    for evt in pgSoup.select('div[set]>div:last-child'):
        if evt.parent.select(f':scope>div:first-child+div+div'):
            cgVals = [v.get_text(' ').strip() if v else defaultVal for v in [
                evt.parent.select_one(s) for s in
                [':scope>div:first-child+div>div:first-child',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2)',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type']]]
            current_group = dict(zip(['date', 'country', 'league'], cgVals))
            if pgDate: current_group['date'] = pgDate

        evtRow = {'date': current_group.get('date', defaultVal)}

        for k, v in evtSel.items():
            v = evt.select_one(v).get_text(' ') if evt.select_one(v) else defaultVal
            evtRow[k] = ' '.join(v.split()) if isinstance(v, str) else v
        evtTeams = evt.select('a div>a[title]')
        evtRow['game'] = ' – '.join(a['title'] for a in evtTeams)
        evtRow['country'] = current_group.get('country', defaultVal)
        evtRow['league'] = current_group.get('league', defaultVal)

        events.append(evtRow)
    return events


def parse_data(url, return_urls=False):
    print(f'Parsing URL: {url}\n')
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[set]>div:last-child a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)")))
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    scroll_pause_time = 2

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")

    game_data = GameData()
    game_keys = [a for a, av in game_data.__dict__.items() if isinstance(av, list)]
    for row in generate_matches(soup, defaultVal=nan):
        for k in game_keys: getattr(game_data, k).append(row.get(k, nan))
    if return_urls:
        ac_sel = 'div:has(>a.active-item-calendar)'  # a_cont selector
        a_sel = f'{ac_sel}>a[href]:not([href^="#"]):not(.active-item-calendar)'
        a_tags = soup.select(a_sel)

        if a_tags:
            urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags]
            print(f'urls after initial creation: {urls}')

            # Extract the date from the first URL
            last_date_str = urls[0].split('/')[-2]
            print(f'last date str: {last_date_str}')
            last_date = datetime.strptime(last_date_str, '%Y%m%d')

            # Generate the additional URLs
            for i in range(1, 4):
                new_date = last_date - timedelta(days=i)
                new_date_str = new_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
                new_url = f'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/football/{new_date_str}/'
                urls.append(new_url)
                print(f'urls after generating additional URL #{i}: {urls}')
        else:
            urls = []

        print(f'final urls: {urls}')

        if urls and urls[-1].startswith('https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/football/'):
            # Extract the date from the last URL
            last_date_str = urls[0].split('/')[-2]
            print(last_date_str)
        else:
            print('No valid URLs found')
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    games = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5)
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    url_today = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer'
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=(url_today, True))
    game_data_results = pool.imap(parse_data, urls)

    # ########################### BUILD  DATAFRAME ############################
    game_data_dfList, added_todayGame = [], False
    for game_data in game_data_results:
        try:
            game_data_dfList.append(pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__))
            if not added_todayGame:
                game_data_dfList += [pd.DataFrame(game_data_today.__dict__)]
                added_todayGame = True
        except Exception as e:
            game_n = len(game_data_dfList) + 1
            print(f'Error tabulating game_data_df#{game_n}:\n{repr(e)}')
    try:
        games = pd.concat(game_data_dfList, ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error concatenating DataFrames:', repr(e))
    # #########################################################################
    print('!?NO GAMES?!' if games is None else games)
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal  # a little extra insurance
    import gc

    gc.collect()

games.to_csv()
```

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\scratches\scratch.py", line 165, in <module>
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=(url_today, True))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 261, in apply
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\scratches\scratch.py", line 97, in parse_data
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[set]>div:last-child a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)")))
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\Project\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I am not sure what is the correct css selector in my case for

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[set]>div:last-child a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)")))
```

What should it be?

Comment: So you are trying to select a non-hidden `div` that is a sibling of an anchor that has a child anchor with the title attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try using this:

```
"div[set]>div:last-child a[title]~div:not(.hidden)"
```

instead of:

```
"div[set]>div:last-child a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I am getting nan values for time game  score  home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds  `def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'p.whitespace-nowrap',
        'game': 'a div:has(>a[title])',
        'score': 'a a[title]+div:has(+a[title])',
        'home_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)',
        'draw_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)+div:nth-last-of-type(3)',
        'away_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:nth-last-of-type(2)',
    }` . can you please help here?

Comment: @PyNoob, I would be able to help if you could show where these values lie in the webpage as I'm not able to locate the elements using the given selector path

Comment: [inspect element](https://imgur.com/a/3T1FFDI) The scores available near the games is the selector element. That is not being captured. What would be the correct selector element?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, and you need result of the match, selector can be a bit simple.

Each match block contains unique attribute `r-e-s-u-l-t` with it's value.
So, to scrap results you just need to find elements by CSS: `.eventRow [r-e-s-u-l-t]` and get attribute `r-e-s-u-l-t`.

If you don't want to get empty " - " results, you can define XPATH: `//*[contains(@class, 'eventRow')]//*[@r-e-s-u-l-t and not(@r-e-s-u-l-t = '')]`

[image]

Comment: Can you please help rewrite my `def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None)`?

Comment: Can you please help me construct the CSS extractor?