# What should be the correct CSS selectors with classes in this code?

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract game data from the site https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/football/

The selectors I have constructed are as:

```
def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'div.main-row p.flex',
        'game': 'div.main-row a[title]',
        'score': 'a a[title]+div:has(+a[title])',
        'home_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)',
        'draw_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)+div:nth-last-of-type(3)',
        'away_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:nth-last-of-type(2)',
    }

    events, current_group = [], {}
    pgDate = pgSoup.select_one('h1.title[id="next-matches-h1"]')
    if pgDate: pgDate = pgDate.get_text().split(',', 1)[-1].strip()
    for evt in pgSoup.select('div[set]>div:last-child'):
        if evt.parent.select(f':scope>div:first-child+div+div'):
            cgVals = [v.get_text(' ').strip() if v else defaultVal for v in [
                evt.parent.select_one(s) for s in
                [':scope>div:first-child+div>div:first-child',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2)',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type']]]
            current_group = dict(zip(['date', 'country', 'league'], cgVals))
            if pgDate: current_group['date'] = pgDate

        evtRow = {'date': current_group.get('date', defaultVal)}

        for k, v in evtSel.items():
            v = evt.select_one(v).get_text(' ') if evt.select_one(v) else defaultVal
            evtRow[k] = ' '.join(v.split()) if isinstance(v, str) else v
        evtTeams = evt.select('a div>a[title]')
        evtRow['game'] = ' – '.join(a['title'] for a in evtTeams)
        evtRow['country'] = current_group.get('country', defaultVal)
        evtRow['league'] = current_group.get('league', defaultVal)

        events.append(evtRow)
    return events
```

I am getting the below dataframe:

```
              date  time game  score  home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds                  country                          league
0     25 July 2023   NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN                Argentina                  Reserve League
1     25 July 2023   NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN                Argentina                  Reserve League
2     25 July 2023   NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN                Argentina                  Reserve League
3     25 July 2023   NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN                Argentina                  Reserve League
4     25 July 2023   NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN                   Norway            Division 3 - Group 6
```

I am getting NaN values for time,  game, score, home_odds, draw_odds and away_odds.
What would be the correct element selector to get all the rows populated?

example dataframe:

```
   Unnamed: 0         date   time                                  game  score home_odds draw_odds away_odds  country   league
0           0  01 Apr 2023  01:00  Widad Adabi de Boufarik – Temouchent  1 – 1      2.38      2.93      3.06  Algeria  Ligue 2
1           1  01 Apr 2023  01:00                   Relizane – Oued Sly  1 – 2     10.02      5.00      1.28  Algeria  Ligue 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the additional question you asked in your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759146/what-is-the-correct-css-selector-in-this-code/76759214#76759214) post, Here's the complete solution:

```py
import time
import threading
import pandas as pd
from math import nan
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'div>div>div[class="flex basis-[10%]"]',
        'game': 'a div:has(>a[title])',
        'score': 'a[title]~div:not(.hidden)',
        'home_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(2)',
        'draw_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(3)',
        'away_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(4)'
    }

    events, current_group = [], {}
    pgDate = pgSoup.select_one('h1.title[id="next-matches-h1"]')
    if pgDate: pgDate = pgDate.get_text().split(',', 1)[-1].strip()
    for evt in pgSoup.select('div[set]>div:last-child'):
        if evt.parent.select(f':scope>div:first-child+div+div'):
            cgVals = [v.get_text(' ').strip() if v else defaultVal for v in [
                evt.parent.select_one(s) for s in
                [':scope>div:first-child+div>div:first-child',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2)',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type']]]
            current_group = dict(zip(['date', 'country', 'league'], cgVals))
            if pgDate: current_group['date'] = pgDate

        evtRow = {'date': current_group.get('date', defaultVal)}

        for k, v in evtSel.items():
            v = evt.select_one(v).get_text(' ') if evt.select_one(v) else defaultVal
            evtRow[k] = ' '.join(v.split()) if isinstance(v, str) else v
        # evtTeams = evt.select('a div>a[title]')
        evtTeams = evt.select('div[class^="relative w-full flex-col"]>a')
        evtRow['game'] = ' – '.join(a['title'] for a in evtTeams)
        evtRow['country'] = current_group.get('country', defaultVal)
        evtRow['league'] = current_group.get('league', defaultVal)

        events.append(evtRow)
    return events


def parse_data(url, return_urls=False):
    print(f'Parsing URL: {url}\n')
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[set]>div:last-child")))
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    scroll_pause_time = 2

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")

    game_data = GameData()
    game_keys = [a for a, av in game_data.__dict__.items() if isinstance(av, list)]
    for row in generate_matches(soup, defaultVal=nan):
        for k in game_keys: getattr(game_data, k).append(row.get(k, nan))
    if return_urls:
        ac_sel = 'div:has(>a.active-item-calendar)'  # a_cont selector
        a_sel = f'{ac_sel}>a[href]:not([href^="#"]):not(.active-item-calendar)'
        a_tags = soup.select(a_sel)

        if a_tags:
            urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags]
            print(f'urls after initial creation: {urls}')

            # Extract the date from the first URL
            last_date_str = urls[0].split('/')[-2]
            print(f'last date str: {last_date_str}')
            last_date = datetime.strptime(last_date_str, '%Y%m%d')

            # Generate the additional URLs
            for i in range(1, 4):
                new_date = last_date - timedelta(days=i)
                new_date_str = new_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
                new_url = f'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/football/{new_date_str}/'
                urls.append(new_url)
                print(f'urls after generating additional URL #{i}: {urls}')
        else:
            urls = []

        print(f'final urls: {urls}')

        if urls and urls[-1].startswith('https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/football/'):
            # Extract the date from the last URL
            last_date_str = urls[0].split('/')[-2]
            print(last_date_str)
        else:
            print('No valid URLs found')
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    games = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5)
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    url_today = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer'
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=(url_today, True))
    game_data_results = pool.imap(parse_data, urls)

    # ########################### BUILD  DATAFRAME ############################
    game_data_dfList, added_todayGame = [], False
    for game_data in game_data_results:
        try:
            game_data_dfList.append(pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__))
            if not added_todayGame:
                game_data_dfList += [pd.DataFrame(game_data_today.__dict__)]
                added_todayGame = True
        except Exception as e:
            game_n = len(game_data_dfList) + 1
            print(f'Error tabulating game_data_df#{game_n}:\n{repr(e)}')
    try:
        games = pd.concat(game_data_dfList, ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error concatenating DataFrames:', repr(e))
    # #########################################################################
    print('!?NO GAMES?!' if games is None else games)
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal  # a little extra insurance
    import gc

    gc.collect()

    games.to_csv()
```

output:

```
             date              time                                             game  score home_odds draw_odds away_odds                  country                        league
0    25 July 2023             00:00                           Nordsjaelland – Viborg  4 – 1      1.84      3.86      4.08                  Denmark                     Superliga
1    25 July 2023             00:00                       FK Panevezys – Siauliai FA  2 – 0      2.02      3.24      3.69                Lithuania                        A Lyga
2    25 July 2023             00:00                       Sandefjord 2 – Mjondalen 2  3 – 1      1.43      5.27      5.07                   Norway     Division 3 - Group 4 2023
3    25 July 2023             00:00                             Rosenborg 2 – Tiller  0 – 2      1.24      6.70      8.02                   Norway          Division 3 - Group 5
4    25 July 2023             00:00                           Asker – Sarpsborg 08 2  5 – 1      1.92      4.18      3.01                   Norway          Division 3 - Group 6
5    25 July 2023             00:00                                Viking – Aalesund  3 – 1      1.24      6.44     10.03                   Norway                   Eliteserien
6    25 July 2023             00:00                    Korona Kielce – Slask Wroclaw  1 – 1      2.27      3.34      3.06                   Poland                   Ekstraklasa
7    25 July 2023             00:00                                 Sirius – Mjallby  2 – 3      2.25      3.37      3.20                   Sweden                   Allsvenskan
8    25 July 2023             00:00                               GAIS – Vasteras SK  0 – 2      1.77      3.71      4.12                   Sweden                    Superettan
9    25 July 2023             00:00                         Helsingborg – Trelleborg  1 – 3      1.99      3.41      3.57                   Sweden                    Superettan
10   26 July 2023             00:00                                 Gebenbach – Cham  2 – 2      1.82      3.93      3.49                  Germany          Oberliga Bayern Nord
11   26 July 2023             00:00                             Ingolstadt II – ATSV  2 – 0      2.03      3.65      3.13                  Germany          Oberliga Bayern Nord
12   26 July 2023             00:00                      Hottur / Huginn – Volsungur  2 – 1      1.97      4.09      3.06                  Iceland                    Division 2
13   26 July 2023             00:00                Heracles (Ned)  – FC Emmen (Ned)   1 – 0      1.84      3.76      3.67                    World                 Club Friendly
14   26 July 2023             00:00              Koln II (Ger)  – TuS Koblenz (Ger)   1 – 0      1.71      3.91      4.10                    World                 Club Friendly
15   26 July 2023             00:15                   Lahr (Ger)  – Bahlinger (Ger)   0 – 4      6.58      5.27      1.36                    World                 Club Friendly
16   26 July 2023             00:30                        Erlbach – Kirchanschoring  1 – 0      2.82      3.33      2.31                  Germany           Oberliga Bayern Süd
17   26 July 2023             00:30                  Baumberg (Ger)  – Bonner (Ger)   2 – 0      2.73      3.65      2.28                    World                 Club Friendly
18   26 July 2023             00:45                            Zenit – Akhmat Grozny  2 – 0      1.51      4.34      5.81                   Russia                   Russian Cup
19   26 July 2023             01:00           Dnipro-1 (Ukr)  – Panathinaikos (Gre)   1 – 3      3.44      3.06      2.25                   Europe              Champions League
20   26 July 2023             01:00              D. Zagreb (Cro)  – FC Astana (Kaz)   4 – 0      1.33      4.83     10.01                   Europe              Champions League
21   26 July 2023             01:00                   TNS (Wal)  – Hesperange (Lux)   1 – 1      2.53      3.26      2.75                   Europe      Europa Conference League
22   26 July 2023             01:00            Hamrun (Mlt)  – Dinamo Tbilisi (Geo)   2 – 1      3.11      3.17      2.31                   Europe      Europa Conference League
23   26 July 2023             01:00                           Thor Akureyri – Grotta  3 – 1      2.33      3.70      2.59                  Iceland                    Division 1
24   26 July 2023             01:00                Fjallabyggd – Fjardabyggd/Leiknir  1 – 3      3.24      3.86      1.91                  Iceland                    Division 2
25   26 July 2023             01:00                     U. San Martin – Comerciantes  1 – 0      1.94      3.45      3.55                     Peru                        Liga 2
26   26 July 2023             01:00                Fleetwood (Eng)  – Preston (Eng)   0 – 0      2.95      3.42      2.24                    World                 Club Friendly
27   26 July 2023             01:00         AFC Wimbledon (Eng)  – Portsmouth (Eng)   1 – 0      3.44      3.56      1.96                    World                 Club Friendly
28   26 July 2023             01:00                 MK Dons (Eng)  – Coventry (Eng)   1 – 5      3.95      3.60      1.83                    World                 Club Friendly
29   26 July 2023             01:00          Rotherham (Eng)  – Sheffield Utd (Eng)   1 – 0      4.02      3.75      1.78                    World                 Club Friendly
30   26 July 2023             01:00           Swansea (Wal)  – Bristol Rovers (Eng)   0 – 2      1.62      4.02      4.71                    World                 Club Friendly
31   26 July 2023             01:00         Telstar (Ned)  – Rijnsburgse Boys (Ned)   1 – 0      1.81      4.01      3.52                    World                 Club Friendly
32   26 July 2023             01:00                  Murcia (Esp)  – Zaragoza (Esp)   0 – 1      2.85      3.23      2.41                    World                 Club Friendly
33   26 July 2023             01:00              St. Gallen (Sui)  – Valencia (Esp)   1 – 3      3.32      3.62      1.99                    World                 Club Friendly
34   26 July 2023             01:00                  FC Porto (Por)  – Wolves (Eng)   0 – 1      1.78      3.92      3.86                    World                 Club Friendly
35   26 July 2023             01:00        Kidderminster (Eng)  – Northampton (Eng)   2 – 2      3.45      3.45      2.00                    World                 Club Friendly
36   26 July 2023             01:00          Doncaster (Eng)  – Sheffield Wed (Eng)   1 – 0      4.62      4.07      1.62                    World                 Club Friendly
.
.
.
.
333   01 Aug 2023             00:00                                    Orebro – GAIS      –      3.59      3.41      1.98                   Sweden                    Superettan
334   01 Aug 2023             00:00                           Utsikten – Helsingborg      –      1.98      3.44      3.57                   Sweden                    Superettan
335   01 Aug 2023             01:00                      Def. de Belgrano – Flandria      –      1.74      3.21      5.14                Argentina              Primera Nacional
336   01 Aug 2023             01:00                      Debrecen – Mezokovesd-Zsory      –      1.87      3.63      3.72                  Hungary                 OTP Bank Liga
337  24 July 2023             00:00                                    Flora – Narva  1 – 4      1.09      9.19     21.37                  Estonia                  Meistriliiga
338  24 July 2023             00:00                         Dalvik/Reynir – Olafsvik  3 – 0      2.20      3.79      2.73                  Iceland                    Division 2
339  24 July 2023             00:00                          Longford – St. Patricks  1 – 2     15.46      6.96      1.15                  Ireland                       FAI Cup
340  24 July 2023             00:00                            Rudar – Arsenal Tivat  0 – 1      2.26      3.16      3.08               Montenegro          Prva Crnogorska Liga
341  24 July 2023             00:00                          Vilaverdense – Casa Pia  0 – 2      4.19      3.41      1.85                 Portugal                    League Cup
342  24 July 2023             00:00                        Os Belenenses – Famalicao  3 – 2      3.48      3.43      2.03                 Portugal                    League Cup
343  24 July 2023             00:00                       FK Rostov – Fakel Voronezh  2 – 1      2.11      3.14      3.93                   Russia                Premier League
344  24 July 2023             00:00                                  Sochi – Baltika  2 – 0      2.05      3.43      3.78                   Russia                Premier League
.
.
.
362  22 July 2023             00:00                         Vendsyssel – Sonderjyske  1 – 1      2.45      3.52      2.73                  Denmark                  1st Division
363  22 July 2023             00:00                                  Hillerod – Koge  0 – 4      2.28      3.50      2.92                  Denmark                  1st Division
364  22 July 2023             00:00                        Midtjylland – Hvidovre IF  1 – 0      1.32      5.45      9.05                  Denmark                     Superliga
365  22 July 2023             00:00                         Atlantis – P-Iirot Rauma  2 – 1      1.35      5.86      6.07                  Finland              Kakkonen Group B
366  22 July 2023             00:00                           Burghausen – Bayern II  3 – 3      4.27      4.26      1.63                  Germany           Regionalliga Bayern
```

Few things to note:

- Use these selectors:

  ```
  evtSel = {
        'time': 'div>div>div[class="flex basis-[10%]"]',
        'game': 'a div:has(>a[title])',
        'score': 'a[title]~div:not(.hidden)',
        'home_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(2)',
        'draw_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(3)',
        'away_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(4)'
    }

  evtTeams = evt.select('div[class^="relative w-full flex-col"]>a')
  ```

  Instead of:

  ```
  evtSel = {
        'time': 'div.main-row p.flex',
        'game': 'div.main-row a[title]',
        'score': 'a a[title]+div:has(+a[title])',
        'home_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)',
        'draw_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)+div:nth-last-of-type(3)',
        'away_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:nth-last-of-type(2)',
    }

  evtTeams = evt.select('a div>a[title]')
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just did one change from your code edit I used  `'time': 'div.next-m\\:flex-col p',` instead of `'time': 'div>div>div[class="flex basis-[10%]"]` as there were a few values where matches were penalties being reflected in the time column. I took help of bing chat for that. The rest is all from your code. I am still figuring out how to download HTML and then iterate over that to get what I want. Thank you again!

Comment: the solution you posted helped me heaps however the webpage changed. can you please help answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76998689/why-am-i-getting-na-values-in-this-scraper-code) ? Also, can I select the elements by xpath instead of css selectors as it seems easier for me; all I have to copy the selectors and replace them in my code? Help would be greatly appreciated