# Why am I getting na values in this scraper code?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is my code to generate matches table:

```
import os
import time
import threading
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import nan
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import re


class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Un-comment next line to supress logging:
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'div.next-m\\:flex-col p',
        'game': 'a[title]',
        'score': 'a[title]~div:not(.hidden)',
        'home_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(2)',
        'draw_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(3)',
        'away_odds': 'div[class^="flex-center flex-col gap-1 border-l border-black-ma"]:nth-child(4)'
    }

    events, current_group = [], {}
    pgDate = pgSoup.select_one('h1.title[id="next-matches-h1"]')
    if pgDate: pgDate = pgDate.get_text().split(',', 1)[-1].strip()
    for evt in pgSoup.select('div[set]>div:last-child'):
        if evt.parent.select(f':scope>div:first-child+div+div'):
            cgVals = [v.get_text(' ').strip() if v else defaultVal for v in [
                evt.parent.select_one(s) for s in
                [':scope>div:first-child+div>div:first-child',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2)',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type']]]
            current_group = dict(zip(['date', 'country', 'league'], cgVals))
            if pgDate: current_group['date'] = pgDate

        evtRow = {'date': current_group.get('date', defaultVal)}

        for k, v in evtSel.items():
            v = evt.select_one(v).get_text(' ') if evt.select_one(v) else defaultVal
            evtRow[k] = ' '.join(v.split()) if isinstance(v, str) else v
        # evtTeams = evt.select('a div>a[title]')
        evtTeams = evt.select('a[title]')
        evtRow['game'] = ' - '.join(a['title'] for a in evtTeams)
        evtRow['country'] = current_group.get('country', defaultVal)
        evtRow['league'] = current_group.get('league', defaultVal)

        events.append(evtRow)

    return events


def parse_data(url, return_urls=False):
    print(f'Parsing URL: {url}\n')
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.get(url)
    # Wait for the first match element to be present
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    match_element_class = "border-black-borders.group.flex"  # Class of the match element
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f".{match_element_class}")))

    # Now, check if the first match element contains match data
    first_match_element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f".{match_element_class}")
    match_data_indicator = "participant-name"  # Class indicating match data
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, match_data_indicator)))
    
    # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
    scroll_pause_time = 4
    try:
        # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
        scroll_pause_time = 4

        # Get scroll height
        last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        while True:
            # Scroll down to bottom
            browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            # Wait to load page
            time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
            new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            last_height = new_height
        # ########## For page to scroll to the end ###########
        # If browser stalls and gives timeout exception refresh the browser
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout exception occurred, refreshing the page...")
        browser.refresh()

    time.sleep(5)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")

    game_data = GameData()
    game_keys = [a for a, av in game_data.__dict__.items() if isinstance(av, list)]
    for row in generate_matches(soup, defaultVal=nan):
        for k in game_keys: getattr(game_data, k).append(row.get(k, nan))
    if return_urls:
        ac_sel = 'div:has(>a.active-item-calendar)'  # a_cont selector
        a_sel = f'{ac_sel}>a[href]:not([href^="#"]):not(.active-item-calendar)'
        a_tags = soup.select(a_sel)

        if a_tags:
            urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags]
            # print(f'urls after initial creation: {urls}')

            # Extract the date from the first URL
            last_date_str = urls[0].split('/')[-2]
            print(f'last date str: {last_date_str}')
            last_date = datetime.strptime(last_date_str, '%Y%m%d')

            # Generate the additional URLs
            for i in range(1, 4):
                new_date = last_date - timedelta(days=i)
                new_date_str = new_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
                print(f'new dates: {new_date_str}')
                new_url = f'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/football/{new_date_str}/'
                urls.append(new_url)
                # print(f'urls after generating additional URL #{i}: {urls}')
        else:
            urls = []

        # print(f'final urls: {urls}')

        if urls and urls[-1].startswith('https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/football/'):
            # Extract the date from the last URL
            last_date_str = urls[0].split('/')[-2]
            print(last_date_str)
        else:
            print('No valid URLs found')
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    games = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5)
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    url_today = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer'
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=(url_today, True))
    game_data_results = pool.imap(parse_data, urls)

    # ########################### BUILD  DATAFRAME ############################
    game_data_dfList, added_todayGame = [], False
    for game_data in game_data_results:
        try:
            game_data_dfList.append(pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__))
            if not added_todayGame:
                game_data_dfList += [pd.DataFrame(game_data_today.__dict__)]
                added_todayGame = True
        except Exception as e:
            game_n = len(game_data_dfList) + 1
            print(f'Error tabulating game_data_df#{game_n}:\n{repr(e)}')
    try:
        games = pd.concat(game_data_dfList, ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error concatenating DataFrames:', repr(e))
    # #########################################################################
    print('!?NO GAMES?!' if games is None else games)
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted":
    del threadLocal  # a little extra insurance
    import gc

    gc.collect()

games.to_csv()
```

It usually scrapes data in this format:

```
 date        | time   | game                                 | score   |   home_odds |   draw_odds |   away_odds | country   | league
-------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------
 01 Apr 2023 | 01:00  | Widad Adabi de Boufarik – Temouchent | 1 – 1   |        2.38 |        2.93 |        3.06 | Algeria   | Ligue 2
 01 Apr 2023 | 01:00  | Relizane – Oued Sly                  | 1 – 2   |       10.02 |        5    |        1.28 | Algeria   | Ligue 2
```

However I am getting nan values:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date, time, game, score, home_odds, draw_odds, away_odds, country, league]
Index: []
```

Why is this the case and how can I get the desired data in the requisite roles?

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris*

Comment: This can't be your full code.  Two functions are **defined** but never **called**.

Comment: Apologies. I updated the entire code now